# how to I copy structure char variable into another char array

Tags: c, string, structure

```
struct student
{
    char name[50];
    int rollno;
    float marks;
};
int main()
{
    char nam[50];
    int i = 0, n=5;
    struct student s1[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       nam[i] = s1[i].name;
     }
}
```

In given code, I am unable to copy s1[i].name in nam[i], I tried all the copy function but it's giving me error every time.

Comment: Use `strcpy()`. This should be explained in every C tutorial on strings.

Comment: `nam` is just one string, not an array of strings. Why are you trying to copy 5 names into it?

Comment: `nam[i]` is just a single character. How do you expect to put a whole name there? What result are you trying to get?

Comment: @Bhavin Patil "I tried all the copy function but it's giving me error every time." As for me then I do not know all copy functions as you ::)

Comment: `strcpy(nam, s[i].nam)` shouldn't give you an error.

Comment: You need to study arrays then pointers then strings, in that order. I wrote a beginner FAQ about C strings here: [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849) You've written beginner bug #1 in that FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

This ...

> ```
>        nam[i] = s1[i].name;
> ```

... does not make sense because `name[i]` is *one* `char`, whereas `s1[i].name` is an array of 50 `char`s.  Moreover, your loop is over the number of elements of `s1` (5), which is much less than the number of elements of `nam` or `s1[i].name`.

Supposing that you really do want `s1` to be an array of `struct student` as opposed to just one struct, you probably want to use `strcpy()`. However, you might want or need to use `memcpy()` (or an element by element copy loop) depending on the nature of the contents of `s1` and its elements and any artificial requirements on the exercise.

The `strcpy()` variation would look like this:

```
       strcpy(nam, s1[i].name);
       // do something with nam ...
```

That depends on the source array to contain a null-terminated string, which is not guaranteed to be the case in the demo program, which never puts any data in `s1` or its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of little things working against you in this code, eg the following...

```
int i = 0, n=5;
struct student s1[n];
```

...creates a variable length array of `struct student`, preventing an initializer from being a viable path.  But if for the sake of illustration you can live with a non-VLA version, then try this:

```
//Use a hard-coded to `5`,  to create an array of 5 struct student, initialized as shown: 
struct student s1[5] = {{"name1"1, 1.0},("name2",2,2.0},{"name3",3,3.0},{"name4",4,4.0},{"name5",5,5.0}};
```

Next, your current code: `char nam[50];` creates a single uninitialized char array, sufficient for containing only 1 string with up to 49 characters, with a terminating `\0`. If you can, create it like this. (for the sake of learning to copy strings in a loop.)

```
char nam[5][50] = {{0}};//created 5 elements of null terminated char array elements,
```

Then you can do this in your loop:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   strcpy(nam[i], s1[i]name);
}
```

By now (from comments and answers) you should already know that strings cannot be copied using the `=` operator like integers or floating numbers. String functions such as `strcpy()`, or `sprintf()` can be used to populate strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcpy()` I have tried and it's working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).